# asp.net core pass model to view from controller changed view layout

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building website using asp.net core 3.1 following tutorials, I'm working on bootstrap template, now I encountered strange problem that when I pass a strongly typed model to the view the layout of bootstrap not working, but if request the view without sending model it work...

Searching in google doesn't give a result.

Answer (score 0):

Please enter the script and css with the view rendersection you are using and add the bootsrap links there

@Rendersection("Scripts",false) and @Rendersection("Style" ,false) include in layout after go to view add up @section Style (  bootsrap  css  link  )  and down view  add section script

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem, It's was in svg-icons calls, it was starts with "~/svg-icons/" so I replaced it with "../svg-icons/", so the problem solved.